# Flutter: login through a webview

Tags: authentication, webview, flutter

I'm pretty new to Flutter. 
Is there a way to login through a webview into our app?

e.g. In the first page there is this webview where we can do the login. After we logged in, the app takes us in a second page where we can do other stuff.

Comment: There are authentication packages that do that. You should be able to derive a custom solution from their source. I don't know which exactly but they should be in pub.dartlang.org. Perhaps facebook auth (not sure)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In my app I use instagram implicit authentification, which implies to login user in webview and get token from redirect url. I use [flutter_webview_plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_webview_plugin)
Next code builds WebviewScaffold with login url. And it listen for url changes. So when response is redirected to my redirectUrl it parses url to get token. Then you need to save token for following requests in app.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => new _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  final flutterWebviewPlugin = new FlutterWebviewPlugin();

  StreamSubscription _onDestroy;
  StreamSubscription<String> _onUrlChanged;
  StreamSubscription<WebViewStateChanged> _onStateChanged;

  String token;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Every listener should be canceled, the same should be done with this stream.
    _onDestroy.cancel();
    _onUrlChanged.cancel();
    _onStateChanged.cancel();
    flutterWebviewPlugin.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    flutterWebviewPlugin.close();

    // Add a listener to on destroy WebView, so you can make came actions.
    _onDestroy = flutterWebviewPlugin.onDestroy.listen((_) {
      print("destroy");
    });

    _onStateChanged =
        flutterWebviewPlugin.onStateChanged.listen((WebViewStateChanged state) {
      print("onStateChanged: ${state.type} ${state.url}");
    });

    // Add a listener to on url changed
    _onUrlChanged = flutterWebviewPlugin.onUrlChanged.listen((String url) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          print("URL changed: $url");
          if (url.startsWith(Constants.redirectUri)) {
            RegExp regExp = new RegExp("#access_token=(.*)");
            this.token = regExp.firstMatch(url)?.group(1);
            print("token $token");

            saveToken(token);
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                "/home", (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
            flutterWebviewPlugin.close();
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String loginUrl = "someservise.com/auth";

    return new WebviewScaffold(
        url: loginUrl,
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Login to someservise..."),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I'm a little bit stupid, but I don't understand this part:
 if (url.startsWith(Constants.redirectUri))

How do you create "Constants.redirectUri"?

Comment: @LittleMonkey, no, you are not stupid. Just don't know yet something.
Redirect url  is part of implicit authorisation  that Instagtam API uses.  
I ask webview to load url (instagram.com/auth) with my appId. It loads, user put its credentials, then Instagram check it, if it is good, send response with redirectUrl, which I specify in my Instagram Developer's profile. And Instagram adds token to this url. So webview changes url to this redirectUrl. And I parse it to get token.
I hope I explain good enough.
Actually, it's better if you say which service you want to use for authentification

Comment: First of all, thanks. Then, the problem is that I have to login in a web page, so I don't have the redirect. Is it still possible to get the token?

Comment: @littleMonkey, which service are you using? 
It has API and you need to follow it to authorise user. Your service can have other sceme for authentification.

Comment: Ok, I'll check and I will let you know :D. Thank you so much.

Comment: ok. I'll try to help you if I know it. If my answer help, please, don't forget to accept it :)

Comment: In the end I didn't need it, but I'll validate your answer because it works like this.
p.s. thank you so much

Comment: This is an excellent Flutter Oauth example. I pasted it into my Firebase auth demo app and only made a few small changes to make it work with Github's Oauth provider. Thanks for helping me learn how to do Oauth.

Comment: Thanks brother! You saved my day. The solution works perfectly fine with Instagram authentication and getting access_token of the user trying to log into instagram.

Comment: is this possible to do for gmail and facebook login also?

Answer (score 7):

You can use my plugin [flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview), which is a Flutter plugin that allows you to add inline WebViews or open an in-app browser window and has a lot of events, methods, and options to control WebViews.

You can use `onLoadStart` or `onLoadStop` events to detect URL changes. For example, you can get the token:

- from the url
- from cookies
- from localStorage

Full example:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

Future main() async {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: InAppWebViewPage()
    );
  }
}

class InAppWebViewPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InAppWebViewPageState createState() => new _InAppWebViewPageState();
}

class _InAppWebViewPageState extends State<InAppWebViewPage> {
  InAppWebViewController webView;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("InAppWebView")
        ),
        body: Container(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  child: InAppWebView(
      initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.https("next.kemi.ai", "")),
      initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
        android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
          domStorageEnabled: true,
          databaseEnabled: true,
        ),
      ),
      onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
        webView = controller;
      },
      onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, Uri? url) {

      },
      onLoadStop: (InAppWebViewController controller, Uri? url) async {
        if (url?.toString().startsWith("https://myUrl.com/auth-response")??false) {
          // get your token from url
          RegExp regExp = RegExp("access_token=(.*)");
          String? token = regExp.firstMatch(url?.toString()??'')?.group(1);
          print(token);

          // or using CookieManager
          CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.instance();
          Cookie? cookie = await cookieManager.getCookie(
              url: Uri.parse("https://myUrl.com/auth-response"),
              name: "access_token");
          print(cookie?.value??'');

          // or using javascript to get access_token from localStorage
          String? tokenFromJSEvaluation = await controller.evaluateJavascript(source: "localStorage.getItem('access_token')");
          print(tokenFromJSEvaluation);
        }
      },
    )
                ),
              ),
            ]))
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Will you please update your code, cause the plugin or the package has been changed its some properties, like `initialUrl:` changed to `initialUrlRequest:` etc. thank you

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I get my data via this -

```
 InAppWebView(
              initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse(widget.url)),
              initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
                crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(userAgent: "random"),
//Add 'random' to 'userAgent' other wise you get error in webview for google signin.
                android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
                  domStorageEnabled: true,
                  databaseEnabled: true,
                ),
              ),
              onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
                webView = controller;
                showAnimationLoader(context);
              },
              onLoadStop: (InAppWebViewController controller, Uri? url) async {
                Get.back();
                if (url?.toString().contains("my.domain.app") ?? false) {
                  debuggingPrint(
                      message: 'Code : ${url?.queryParameters['code'] ?? ''}');
                  debuggingPrint(
                      message: 'State : ${url?.queryParameters['state'] ?? ''}');
                }
              },
            )
```