# How to close web-view automatically when URL changed in Android Flutter?

Tags: java, android, flutter, native

I want to close Web-View Automatically when URL is Changed. Here is the code i'm used to open a web-view in Flutter Android Application.

```
 GestureDetector(
              child: WebviewScaffold(
                url: webUrl,
                withJavascript: true,
                withLocalStorage: true,
                persistentFooterButtons: <Widget>[
                  RaisedBtn(
                    onPressed: (){
                      Screen();
                      flutterWebviewPlugin.dispose();
                    },
                    text: "Confirm",
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: I think the accepted answer here will help you :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51541258/flutter-login-through-a-webview

Comment: I think the accepted answer here will help you :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51541258/flutter-login-through-a-webview

Comment: I think the accepted answer will help you :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51541258/flutter-login-through-a-webview

Answer (score 0):

please check example below. Flutter webview has single instance which you can retrieve as `FlutterWebviewPlugin()`

```
 import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';

    final _loginWebView = FlutterWebviewPlugin();

    _onUrlChanged = _loginWebView.onUrlChanged.listen((String url) {
            //check is it right url for navigation and navigate back or do nothing
        });
```

**Important!**
Do not forget to dispose it.

Comment: Not working what? Is never been called or what?
Share please minimum reproducible example to understand what not working

Comment: I wan to close flutter web-view when url changed

Comment: And what not working for you? You could handle url changes or what?