# Closing Webview on loading specific URL in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Working on a Flutter App in which I am opening an external webpage using WebView. Is there a way to know when user another page from the initial page and close the webview even before loading it?

More specifically, this is for a Payment process, where the page to enter the payment details is opened using web view. The URL passed to WebView has options to redirect to different web pages depending on different status of the payment. I do not want to show the redirected page using web view. Instead, I want to close web view and show the status using Flutter widget.

Comment: Solved by using onUrlChanged.listen as given in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51541258/flutter-login-through-a-webview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Followed the steps given in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51541258/flutter-login-through-a-webview).

Here is the code.

```
// Add a listener to on url changed
_onUrlChanged =
    flutterWebviewPlugin.onUrlChanged.listen((String url) async {
  if (mounted) {
    //print("URL changed: $url");
    if (url.startsWith(widget.checkoutResult.returnUrl)) {
        // handle success case
    } else if (if (url.startsWith(widget.checkoutResult.cancelUrl)) {
        // Handle cancel case
    }
  }
```

Comment: I face a similar issue, a payment page automatically redirects and I can not detect with navigationDelegate function. So, did you switched to 'flutter_webview_plugi' from 'webview_flutter' package.

Comment: It was flutter_webview_plugin from the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

```
  navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
        if (request.url.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/')) {
          print('blocking navigation to $request}'); # add your code of closing webView
          return NavigationDecision.prevent;
        }
        print('allowing navigation to $request');
        return NavigationDecision.navigate;
      },
```

Could also disable javascriptMode(`JavascriptMode.disabled`) this would't allow any redirects

Comment: Tried the above using following code. URL is not getting printed.

                 WebView(
                    initialUrl: '${widget.url}',
                    javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                    onPageStarted: (url) {},
                    navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
                      print("#@#@ ${request.url}");